# Why does adding a 2nd option to LIKE seem to undo my date = function?

Tags: sql, sql-like, presto

I'm trying to get results that allow me to use 2 options for the LIKE clause, but also have a specific date.  This query gives me only rows that have a dt of 2021-06-04

```
SELECT * FROM table.name
where
dt = date '2021-06-04'
```

However, this query satisfies the 2 LIKE options, but seems to completely disregard my dt = criteria.  It's giving me results from all time, not just 2021-06-04

```
SELECT * FROM table.name
where
dt = date '2021-06-04'
and
item_code like 'RNW%'
OR
item_code like 'XX%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions are being processed left to right, so what you wrote will essentially work like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table.name
where
(dt = date '2021-06-04' and item_code like 'RNW%')
OR
item_code like 'XX%'
```

To fix it, add parentheses to group the conditions the way you want:

```
SELECT * FROM table.name
where 
dt = date '2021-06-04'
and
( item_code like 'RNW%' OR item_code like 'XX%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

as Gordon mentioned you have to learn more about priorities of operations in sql , you can chnage priorities by using parenthesis

```
SELECT * FROM table.name
where
dt = date '2021-06-04'
and (item_code like 'RNW%' OR item_code like 'XX%')
```